# ImageView error Android Studio with ConstraintLayout

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I have a problem with the xml file of an activity in android studio the code is:

```xml
    
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".IntroductoryActivity">
    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bg_snow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="900dp"
            android:src="@drawable/bg_snow"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I need the ImageView not to change:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is your mean about "I need the ImageView not to change"? please more explain

Comment: In android 7, 8 and 9 it works, but I have a device with android 5.1.1 it does not work, the project is being carried out in android 5.0

Comment: When you run project do you get any error?? or just image doesn't show??

Comment: It comes out and says an error has simply been obtained, this is in the second image that I post @SINA

Comment: To better understand, the screenshot of your AndroidStudio XML layout is showing the image that you want to obtain, but on Android 5 is not rendered like this, correct?

Comment: It only happens in android 5 the one I have, And if it is exactly what happens, it is simple, it is only an image, and as you can see in the capture it is running normal in the design part and it also runs in android 7 8 and 9 but not in 5 @LucaPizzini

Comment: In your project window, on Android Studio, check if your bg_snow drawable is in both drawable and drawable-v24 folders.

Comment: @LucaPizzini Indeed it is in both, I have no problems with the image, only that in android 5.0 the application is closed, while in android 9, 8 and 7 it shows normal